# Error When Saving File to Downloads in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to save csv file locally to 'Downloads' folder, but whenever I try to do it, I get an error, here's the code:

```
getDownloads(List<Email> mailList) async {
List<List<dynamic>> rows = List<List<dynamic>>();
for (int i = 0; i < mailList.length; i++) {
  List<dynamic> row = List();
  row.add(mailList[i].id);
  row.add(mailList[i].email);
  rows.add(row);
  setState(() {
    mailList = finalExport;
  });
}
await SimplePermissions.requestPermission(Permission.WriteExternalStorage);
bool checkPermission = await SimplePermissions.checkPermission(
    Permission.WriteExternalStorage);
if (checkPermission) {
  //String csv = const ListToCsvConverter().convert(rows);
  String dir = await ExtStorage.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
      ExtStorage.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS);

  String file = "$dir";
  print(file);
  File f = new File(file + "/maillist.csv");
  String csv = const ListToCsvConverter().convert(rows);
  f.writeAsString(csv);

}
```

}

Now I am getting this error, I am not sure what the issue is:

```
  [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(177)] Unhandled Exception: MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method getExternalStoragePublicDirectory on channel ext_storage)
```

I am using the **ext_storage: ^1.0.3** library for locating the Downloads directory.

Comment: run **flutter clean** command and rebuild app

Comment: Oh that seems to do the trick. Thank you a lot!

Comment: I can mark it complete if you add a post below.

Comment: I have added a post now you can mark it ccmplete

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Run **flutter clean** command and rebuild app